# C++ argument of type "std::string(*)[3][5][30]" is incompatible with parameter of type "std::string *"

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm working on a code that will take a single user input and split it into five substrings. Partway through, I discovered this error I got when calling the function Split_Input. I've never gotten this before and I feel like there's an easy solution, I just can't put my finger on it. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//This function will take the user input and split it into five substrings
void Split_Input(string *database, int ROWS) {
    //------USER INPUT----------
    cout << "Enter your first name, last name, age, phone number, and email address. \n";
    cout << "Make sure you separate each value with a comma!\n";
    string info;
    cin >> info;
    //------GETTING THE SUBSTRINGS--------
    //This value will count each comma and sort the substrings
    int column_count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; info[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (info[i] == ',') {
            column_count++;
            continue;
        }
        //The i marks the array's position by reference
        database[ROWS][column_count][&i] = info[i];
    }
}



int main(void)
{
    const int COLUMNS = 5, ROWS = 3, CHARS = 30;
    string database[ROWS][COLUMNS][CHARS];
    Split_Input(database, ROWS);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue which you asked is the type incompability, and error is even tells you what you need to do. So into function `Split_Input` you need pass a `std::string(*)[3][5][30]` and you function call should look like this

```cpp
Split_Input(&database[ROWS][COLUMNS][CHARS], ROWS);
```

I don't for what the heck you need adress in this line:

```cpp
database[ROWS][column_count][&i] = info[i];
```

BTW, you can replace searching comma you can replace with `string.find(',')`.
I understand it is your beginning with C++, so feel free to ask questions.